Number of left ideals in the simple components of groups algebras
Let $G$ be a finite group and $K$ a field with characteristic zero. Suppose $G$ has $m$ irreducible $K$-representation $W_i$ with character $\chi_i$. $KG$ is semisimple algebra, and
$$KG=KGe_1 \times \cdots \times KGe_m,$$
where $e_i$ for $1 \le i \le m$ are centrally primitive idempotents of $KG$ corresponding to $\chi_i$.
Each $A=KGe_i$ is a simple algebra and has a minimal left ideal $N$. There are finitely many elements $\alpha_j \in A$ such that $A=N \alpha_1 + \cdots + N \alpha_{n}$. Equivalently, we have the left $A$-module isomorphism ${}_{A}A\cong N^n$.
I am looking for the value $n$.
Is there any relation between $n$ and $\dim_K(W_i)=\chi_i(1)$?
If $K$ is a splitting field of $G$, is $n=\chi_i(1)$? If yes, can we extend it to non-splitting fields to get something like $n=\frac{\dim_K(W_i)}{\dim_K(\text{End}_{G}(W_i))}$?

As usual it all boils down to a careful study of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem. The simple factors $A_i = K[G] e_i$ of the group algebra have the form $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ where $D_i = \text{End}_G(W_i)^{op}$ are division algebras over $K$. This means their unique simple module is $W_i \cong D_i^{n_i}$, and $M_{n_i}(D_i)$ is a direct sum of $n_i$ copies of this simple module, so $n_i$ is the value of $n$ you're looking for and it is given by
$$n_i = \dim_{D_i}(W_i) = \frac{\dim_K W_i}{\dim_K D_i}.$$

Thank you. How can we show $W_i$ and $D_i^{n_i}$ are left $A_i$-module isomorphic?

@khashayar: this is, again, part of the statement of the Artin-Wedderburn theorem itself. The decomposition doesn't come out of nowhere; each simple factor is the part of $K[G]$ acting on the corresponding simple module. I recommend in the strongest terms that if you want to understand any of this you should study the proof of Artin-Wedderburn in detail, it answers all of your questions you've been asking.

It is very nice that you know my history of interactions so you can help me better. Thank you very much.
